# The 10th element of an array does not appear on the UI

Tags: arrays, vb.net, panel, vb.net-2010

I am adding 4 elements of an array (11 elements long) of a class that inherits Panel to the UI using the following procedure:

```
Private Sub AddBowlers()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To _sortList.ToArray.Length - 1
        If CheckSelectedPlayer(_sortList(i).PlayerID) Then       'if the player has not already been selected
            count += 1
            _team(count + 6) = New PickTeamLine(_sortList(i))    'initialise a new line, passing it the current bowler in the team list
            AddHandler _team(count + 6).RemoveButtonClicked, AddressOf RemovePlayer   'add the remove button's event handler
            _team(count + 6).SetBounds(3 * INDENT, INDENT + GAP * (count + 6),
                ViewLine.DefaultWidth, ViewLine.DefaultHeight) 'set the position/size of the current line
            Controls.Add(_team(i + 6))                                                'add the current line to the UI's list of controls
            _team(count + 6).Tag = count + 6                                          'assign a value in the line to store the line number it is on
            MsgBox(_team(count + 6).ActivePlayer.Surname)
        End If

        If count = 4 Then 'if 4 bowlers are selected then exit
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The first 7 objects in the _team array are added fine with a previous procedure, but when run, the 10th element in the array is not added, although it is assigned to the _team array correctly (when count = 3), as the MsgBox appears with the correct surname.

Is there any particular reason why only the 10th element is not added to the UI, even though 1-9 and 11 are added in the correct place?

For reference here is what the form looks like after the _team array has been added. (Each element of _team contains one player's name,bat avg, bowl avg and their remove button)

http://puu.sh/7GN2l.png

Comment: Have you debugged this to see what is happening line by line?  For example, what is the result of `If CheckSelectedPlayer(_sortList(i).PlayerID) Then` during your problem record?  ***Exactly*** what happens at each step when attempting to process record 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your new PickTeamLine like this:

```
_team(count + 6) = New PickTeamLine(_sortList(i))
```

then when adding your control, you use i instead of count

```
Controls.Add(_team(i + 6))
```